# Issues with puppeteer typing in credit card input field

Tags: puppeteer, browser-automation

I'm currently having issues with a credit card field and typing in the card information. On the website where I'm having puppeteer type the card info, because of the way that the website formats the card numbers, puppeteer is NOT typing the full card number. The way the credit card field works is that after typing four numbers is tries to automatically put a space before the next four numbers.

I am typing the card info within an iframe as well. Not sure if that has anything to do with it. here is some of my code:

```
await frame.waitForSelector('#creditCardNumber')

await frame.focus('#creditCardNumber')
await frame.type('#creditCardNumber', "4111111111111111")
```

Something else that I have tried:

```
await frame.$eval('#creditCardNumber', card => {card.value = "4111111111111111"})
```

Something that I have found out is that you can copy and paste the credit card information in and it works just fine. I then tried using the clipboardy module but I can't get it working properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced variable issues with Puppeteer typing the credit card number, and after I introduced a 200ms delay, it worked like a charm:

```
await page.type('input[id=cardNumber]', "4242424242424242", { delay: 200 })
```